# Can I override hibernate annotation mapping in subclass?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an entity like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
Class A {
  private Set<B> setOfB;
  @ManyToMany
  public Set<B> getSetofB() {...};
 }
```

Now I need to cache `Set<B> setOfB`， but I can't modify class `A`, however I can subclass `A` and use the subclass in my application, is it possible to add
`@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)` 
for `Set<B>` in the sublclass?
If I add this directly in my subclass, it give me an error said :

> org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException: Duplicate collection role
>   mapping

I don't know if I can override the mapping for a member in the sublcass in Hibernate.

Comment: Maybe mapping is defined somewhere in xml?

Comment: @JMelnik In the whole project, entities are configured using annotation, we don't have a specific xml configuration file to do this, and I don't want to break that.

Comment: Please provide full class A code.

Comment: @JMelnik Thank you, but the class related to this question has huge dependencies, and will distract you, and it's also credential, I just abstracted it to the simplest form, if you don't mind you can use Foo and Bar to mock A and B.

Comment: You cannot simply extend class, I think you still need to define Inheritance strategy?

Comment: @JMelnik I am only allowed to use single table for both A and SubclassOfA, if I I can edit A, I'll just add cache annotation to setOfB, there won't have any question about this.

Comment: As I See, class A does not extend anything.. Please mock your scenario as much as possible to the real case.